# Subdomain Mapping by Proxy

Tags: subdomain, routing, mod-rewrite

## Background

We are trying to map a subdomain to a regular EE template group, without changing the URL.

Assume that the 'natural' URLs to the templates would look something like this:

`my-domain.com/group`
`my-domain.com/group/url-title`

The desired subdomain set up would therefore look something like this:

`group.my-domain.com`
`group.my-domain.com/url-title`

The rewrite rule we have set up on the subdomain looks something like this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/group/$1 [P]`

which, as I understand, will proxy the request to the 'natural' URL.

## The Problem

The problem we are having is that by the time the proxied request hits the server, the `/group` portion of the URL has been duplicated. So the request ends up looking something like this:

`my-domain.com/group/group/url-title`

which obviously doesn't work.

## Debugging

- If I remove the `[P]` flag, the rewriting works correctly. (i.e. the request ends up looking something like `my-domain.com/group/url-title`).
- I have tried using other segments after the domain in the rewrite rule, (just fake ones e.g. `/abc`) and the same thing happens with them.

Could there be anything ExpressionEngine is doing to handle / map a request which could be affecting a proxied request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I don't completely understand *why* it works, we do have a solution that works, so I thought I would post it here.

The rewrite rule now looks like this:

`RewriteRule ^(?:group)?(.*) http://my-domain.com/group/$1 [P]`

which correctly redirects as expected.